# Angular 4.3 HttpClient - How to use HttpHeaders and interceptor properly?

Tags: angular

I need to send headers to my HttpRequest.

I already searched here and I have already tried with a few answers I have found, but none of them worked.

The headers are not being sent to api and if I inspect the `clonedRequest` object, it does not show the headers. That is my code:

```
public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  // Clone the request to add the new header.
  const clonedRequest = req.clone();

  clonedRequest.headers.set("ModuleId", this.dnnContext.moduleId);
  clonedRequest.headers.set("TabId", this.dnnContext.tabId);

  // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
  return next.handle(clonedRequest);
}
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced similar issue & figured out your 2nd(*TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object*) issue, for some 
reason if you pass number type(it has type check but if var type is `any` it allows & it was the case for me) value in header(`ModuleId` or `TabId` in your case) it throws this error so you can convert it 
to string while passing like:

```
const authReq = req.clone({
  headers: req.headers.set('ModuleId', this.dnnContext.moduleId.toString()).set('TabId', this.dnnContext.tabId.toString())
});
// Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
return next.handle(authReq);
```

Also replied on your github [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18885).

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the instances of classes from the new `HttpClient` module are **immutable**. So you need to reassign all the properties that you mutate. This translates into the following in your case:

```
public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  // Clone the request to add the new header.
  const headers = req.headers.set("ModuleId", this.dnnContext.moduleId).set("TabId", this.dnnContext.tabId);
  const clonedRequest= red.clone({
   headers: headers
  });

  // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
  return next.handle(clonedRequest);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting the following error: TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Comment: I would say that the error isnt related to the http client in any way....

Comment: I was not having this error before migrating, in any case I think this has nothing to do with the headers (I hope)...thanks anyway

Comment: Just found out it has something to do with the Headers:

ERROR TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object
    at HttpHeaders.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common/http.es5.js.HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.es5.js:486)
    at

Comment: I saw the issue in github, lets see what the dev team says. I haven't seen the problem personally.